# Spread one row into several by char in SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, string, oracle, tokenize

I want to split the row for several by '|' char. like attached screenshots.
From:
[image]

to:

[image]

Comment: You can do it using this  WITH CTE1 AS (
select COL1,  regexp_substr(COL2, '[^|]+', 1, 1) as val1, 
       regexp_substr(COL2, '[^|]+', 1, 2) as val2, 
       regexp_substr(COL2, '[^|]+', 1, 3) as val3,
       regexp_substr(COL2, '[^|]+', 1, 4) as val4,
       regexp_substr(COL2, '[^|]+', 1, 5) as val5,
       regexp_substr(COL2, '[^|]+', 1, 6) as val6
       FROM TEST_SPLIT)
       
       SELECT COL1, VAL1 FROM CTE1 WHERE VAL1 IS NOT NULL
       UNION
       SELECT COL1, VAL2 FROM CTE1 WHERE VAL2 IS NOT NULL
       UNION
       SELECT COL1, VAL5 FROM CTE1 WHERE VAL5 IS NOT NULL;

Comment: @mohdatif - this question was **closed as a duplicate**. The linked thread includes many different ways of tokenising strings in Oracle SQL, including using regex. Please don't attempt to shoehorn an answer into a comment (which is never a good idea due to poor layout and lack of formatting). Why not upvote one of the better answers in that thread?

Comment: My intention was just to help the user, anyways will take care from future.